# Redefine TypeError to have a static message

Tags: javascript

My question is quite strange in the sense that it is purely for digging into js features as opposed to it being useful. Is there a way to redefine `window.TypeError` so that I can permanent change the `message` property to something static like `"testing message"`?

Consider this piece of code:

```
try {
  null.f();
}
catch(ex) {
  console.log(ex.message) // should print 'testing message' 
  //but keeps on printing 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'f' of null'
}
```

If I inspect `TypeError` with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window,'TypeError')` I can see it is `configurable:true` so I must be able to override it but I can't seem to get it working.

I have tried all different variations but this is my latest attempt:

```
function MyError() {
 this.message = "testing message";
}

MyError.prototype = Object.create(TypeError.prototype);
MyError.prototype.name = "MyError";
MyError.prototype.constructor = MyError;

Object.defineProperty(window, 'TypeError',
{
    get: function () {
        return MyError;
    }
})
```